# Insight into Redshift Spectrum query error

Tags: amazon-redshift, manifest, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm trying to use Redshift Spectrum to query data in s3.  The data has been crawled by Glue, I've run successful data profile jobs on the files with DataBrew (so I know Glue has correctly read it), and I can see the correct tables in the query editor after creating the schema.  But when I try to run simple queries I get one of two errors:  if it's a small file I get: "ERROR: Parsed manifest is not a valid JSON object...."; if it's a large file I get:  "ERROR: Manifest too large Detail:...".  I suspect it's looking for or believes that the file in the query is a manifest, but I have no idea why or how to address it.  I've followed the documentation as rigorously as possible, and I've replicated the process via a screen share with an AWS tech support rep who is also stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the issue:  error is happening because I had more than one type of file (i.e., files  of differing layouts) in the same s3 folder.  There may be other ways to solve the problem, but isolating one type of file for a given s3 folder solved the problem and allowed Redshift Spectrum to successfully execute queries against my file(s).