# Redshift Spectrum query fails with Parsed manifest is not a valid JSON object

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have an S3 bucket with 5 prefixes / "sub-folders", each containing a set of CSV files that were exported from a legacy database.

The CSV files have been crawled and created a Glue database and tables for each prefix / "sub-folder"

I have created an external schema in Redshift for one of the Glue catalogues and I can list the tables and their columns and datatypes.

When I try a simple query against the external schema:
`SELECT Id FROM "dw"."extSchemaNm"."tableName_csv";`

It fails with:

`ERROR: Parsed manifest is not a valid JSON object. Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error: Parsed manifest is not a valid JSON object. code: 15003 context: Id,field2, field3, etc query: 402746 location: spectrum_manifest.cpp:63 process: padbmaster [pid=16643]`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and found this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70279937/22769755

Basically, the file(s) for each table should be in their own subfolders. Each subfolder should only contain files for one single table and nothing else.